# Carousel - thumbnail não fica ativo ao mudar de slide

Tags: javascript, css, slide, carousel

Estou com um problema pois não consigo deixar o thumbnail ativado usando css, deixa uma imagem como exemplo do quero e o código abaixo. Agradeço!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

   $('#myCarousel').carousel({
     interval: 5000
   });

   $('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-0').html());

   //Handles the carousel thumbnails
   $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').click(function() {
     var id = this.id.substr(this.id.lastIndexOf("-") + 1);
     var id = parseInt(id);
     $('#myCarousel').carousel(id);
   });


   // When the carousel slides, auto update the text
   $('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function(e) {
     var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');
     $('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-' + id).html());
   });
 });
```

```css
  .hide-bullets {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: -40px;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="main_area">
    <!-- Slider -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12" id="slider">
        <!-- Top part of the slider -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-8" id="carousel-bounding-box">
            <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
              <!-- Carousel items -->
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="active item" data-slide-number="0">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=one">
                </div>

                <div class="item" data-slide-number="1">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=two">
                </div>

                <div class="item" data-slide-number="2">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=three">
                </div>

                <div class="item" data-slide-number="3">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=four">
                </div>

                <div class="item" data-slide-number="4">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=five">
                </div>

                <div class="item" data-slide-number="5">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=six">
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Carousel nav -->
              <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> 
              </a>
              <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> 
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-4" id="carousel-text"></div>

          <div id="slide-content" style="display: none;">
            <div id="slide-content-0">
              <h2>Slider One</h2>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
              <p class="sub-text">October 24 2014 - <a href="#">Read more</a>
              </p>
            </div>

            <div id="slide-content-1">
              <h2>Slider Two</h2>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
              <p class="sub-text">October 24 2014 - <a href="#">Read more</a>
              </p>
            </div>

            <div id="slide-content-2">
              <h2>Slider Three</h2>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
              <p class="sub-text">October 24 2014 - <a href="#">Read more</a>
              </p>
            </div>

            <div id="slide-content-3">
              <h2>Slider Four</h2>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
              <p class="sub-text">October 24 2014 - <a href="#">Read more</a>
              </p>
            </div>

            <div id="slide-content-4">
              <h2>Slider Five</h2>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
              <p class="sub-text">October 24 2014 - <a href="#">Read more</a>
              </p>
            </div>

            <div id="slide-content-5">
              <h2>Slider Six</h2>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
              <p class="sub-text">October 24 2014 - <a href="#">Read more</a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/Slider-->

    <div class="row hidden-xs" id="slider-thumbs">
      <!-- Bottom switcher of slider -->
      <ul class="hide-bullets">
        <li class="col-sm-2">
          <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-0">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=one">
          </a>
        </li>

        <li class="col-sm-2">
          <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-1">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=two">
          </a>
        </li>

        <li class="col-sm-2">
          <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-2">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=three">
          </a>
        </li>

        <li class="col-sm-2">
          <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-3">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=four">
          </a>
        </li>

        <li class="col-sm-2">
          <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-4">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=five">
          </a>
        </li>

        <li class="col-sm-2">
          <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-5">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=six">
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apenas adicione no seu metodo `on()`  um seletor para remover o `active` e outro para  colocar o `active` no item referente:

### Exemplo:

```
 $(".thumbnail").removeClass('active');
 $('#carousel-selector-' + id).addClass('active');
```

Veja funcionando no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m3vqg0dg/1/)

Comment: Muito obrigado, era isso mesmo que eu queria.